# If statement need to match multiple possibilities

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to make a small bash script to filter certain files from a few delivery folders of an FTP server, and when the files match a certain file naming convention it should pass.

I created a function to process the folders.

```
#!/bin/bash

function folder_search {
find FILE in `find ${DIR}/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +5 -name "*.doc" `; do
BASENAME=`basename $FILE`
if [[ $BASENAME == $NAMECONV1 or $BASENAME == $NAMECONV2 ]]
then
  "some commands"
else
  "some other commands"
fi
}

#folder 1
DIR=/tmp/folder1
NAMECONV1="ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc"
NAMECONV2="NL[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc"
folder_search

#folder 2
DIR=/tmp/folder2
NAMECONV1="ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc"
NAMECONV2="B[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc"
folder_search
```

There are over 40 folders each with their own accepted naming convention, so I need to have it dynamically in the IF statement by variables.

But I can't find the right set of `[]` `{}` `''` `""` `()` ``` `` ``` to get it working.

Any help on this or a completely different approach would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should properly encapsulate its parameters so that you don't set a global variable every time before calling it.  Perhaps something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# for portability, don't use the function keyword
folder_search () {
    # Don't use uppercase for your private variable names
    local dir=$1
    local pat1=$2
    local pat2=$3
    local filename base
    # Don't loop over `find` with for
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +5 -name "*.doc" -print |
    while IFS='' read -r filename; do
        base=$(basename "$filename")
        if [[ "$base" == $pat1 || "$base" == $pat2 ]]; then
          "some commands"
        else
          "some other commands"
        fi
    done
}

#folder 1
folder_search /tmp/folder1 "ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc" "NL[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc"

#folder 2
folder_search /tmp/folder2 "ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc" "B[0-9][0-9][0-9].doc"
```

The `find -print | while read` loop is still not robust for file names which contain newlines, but at least this copes with horizontal whitespace in the file names, which your original code did not.

Comment: Thanks this is working, and implemented. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

The logical `or` operator in `bash` is `||`:

```
if [[ $BASENAME == $NAMECONV1 || $BASENAME == $NAMECONV2 ]]
```

Comment: I believe I've tested this and it didn't gave me the correct result, but I will try it again.

Comment: This also seemed to work but only if the ${BASENAME} is placed between " "

Comment: Inside `[[ ... ]]`, it shouldn't matter if `$BASENAME` is quoted or not.

Answer (score -1):

Try separating your if statements like this:

```
if [ $this == $that ] || [ $that !- $something ];
```

Should work.

Comment: No need to change from `[[ ... ]]` to `[ ... ]`.